# I am sending some ether from account[0] to account[1] using geth console. But the amount is not getting added to the receiving account

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, blockchain

I tried to mine the transaction using miner.start() command, still account balance remains the same

```
> miner.start(8)
I0428 16:27:15.927553 miner/miner.go:136] Starting mining operation (CPU=8 TOT=9)
true
> I0428 16:27:15.932550 miner/worker.go:514] commit new work on block 393 with 2 txs & 0 uncles. Took 4.9972ms
> miner.stop()
true
```

[image]